# Show that an unrestricted $3$-coloring of a plane triangulation $G$ has an even number of $3$-colored faces

Tags: graph-theory

Show that an unrestricted $3$-coloring of a plane triangulation $G$ has an even number of $3$-colored faces.

Here an unrestricted $3$-coloring means that adjacent vertices can receive the same color. And a $3$-colored face is a face where its frontier has distinct colors in each vertex.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by triangulation of the plane.
Is this infinite or not? If infinite, how can we talk about even or odd number of the 3-colored faces? Can you define this concept more precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea should be something like this below.
Because I've seen somewhere 25+ years ago a competitive math problem of this kind whose solution impressed me quite a lot back then.

Let $s$ be any segment. Let also
$f(s) = 1$ if the two ends/vertices of the segment are colored differently;
$f(s) = 0$ if the two ends are of the same color.

Now for each triangular face $a$ denote $G(a)$ to be the sum of $f(s_{ai})$ for its three sides $s_{ai}$ where $i=1,2,3$.

Obviously $G$ can take only the values $0, 2, 3$.
You can make a few drawings and convince yourself in this.

Now sum $G(a)$ over all triangular faces $a$ and denote this sum by $S$.

On one side: $$S = n_0 \cdot 0 + n_2 \cdot 2 + n_3 \cdot 3$$
where $n_i$ is the number of triangular faces for which $G$ takes the value $i$.

On the other side each segment takes part in exactly two triangles. So in $S$ we  in fact sum up the $f(s)$ values for all segments, but actually each segment $s$ contributes two times its own $f(s)$ to $S$.

Therefore $S$ is even.

But then $n_3$ has to be even (from the above equation).
And this is what we wanted to prove.

*Side note: I don't quite understand what you mean by triangulation of the plane.

Is this infinite? If so, how can we talk about even or odd number of the 3-colored faces?*

Also I see in Wikipedia that different types of triangulations can be defined.

[Triangulation (geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(geometry))

But I am sure this problem (which you state) has something to do with this idea.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. A [plane triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Maximal_planar_graphs) is a maximal plane graph.

Comment: @BigBlinders OK, in that case the argument I provided seems to work fine.